# Mailbox set as read-only when symlinking from an external storage

Tags: macos, mail.app, external-disk, symlink

I have multiple mailboxes and I want to save space by moving some of them in an external storage. I'd like to still be able to view the email using `Mail.app` even if said mailbox is now located in an external storage.

After reading upon it, I symlinked a mailbox `.mbox` from the external storage to the original location `~/Library/Mail/Mailboxes/` however upon opening `Mail.app`, the mailbox that was moved to the external storage is set as read-only and no email can be added to it as well as any email content within the mailbox not being read. The read-only seems to disappear when I directly drag and drop a mail from `Mail.app` to the location of the `.mbox` in the external storage.

The OS is `El Capitan` and the external drive that I worked with is a 1TB HDD seagate drive.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6444842 Can this link help you ?
And this one : https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-read-only-external-drive-problems-on-your-mac--mac-52507

Comment: Would be useful if you included in your question the exact version of Mac OS X & exact version of Mail.app you're using. Also, what type of external storage (SATA SSD? CF flash card? USB stick? etc.)

Comment: Separately from your question -- in general Mac OS Mail.app has been getting worse and worse over the past 10 years as far as reliability goes. Lots of bugs remain unresolved. At some point I found that my sanity was much better preserved by moving to a different mail program:  MailMate.app. https://freron.com

Comment: @gosmond The OS is El Capitan and the external storage is a 1TB HDD seagate drive.

Comment: @iizno I checked the thread that you linked and unfortunately It does not.

Comment: El Capitan (OS X 10.11) was released Sept. 2015 with last security update in July 2018. IMO that makes it considerably less-likely your bounty will get answered because the active user base of 10.11 is probably fairly small at this point.  You might consider testing under OS X 10.14 Mojave or 10.15 Catalina (which have much newer versions of Mail.app as well) to see if your problem is resolved.